# How do I get the integer value of the space key(32) from the String to another String?

Tags: java, string

So i need to have a String and put it into its letter by letter integer value. For example if i have a string "L" it should convert to 76. All the strings that use this method have been moved to all upper case letters. What i've been doing so far has been working until it reaches a space:

```
public static String toNumberValue(String s){
    String numberString = "";
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        int characterCode = (int)(s.charAt(i));
        if(characterCode == 32){
            numberString = numberString + "00";
        }
        else
            numberString = numberString + characterCode;
    }
    System.out.println(numberString);
    return numberString;
}
```

When it reaches a space it just stops there and doesnt print the rest of the string. Please help?

Edit: Here is the main class i used with this. I improted Scanner and used its .next method to read in the input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter string to encode: ");
    String wordIn = input.next();
    String toEncrypt = wordIn.toUpperCase();
    toNumberValue(toEncrypt);
    String encryptedString;



    //encode number string

    //from encoded number string, decode

    //from decoded numbers put it back into letters

}
```

Comment: This program seems to be working for me. What input are you using that it's failing on? See: http://ideone.com/BM11R3

Comment: I was testing it with "hello world" and it would print hello but stop there. However, parameter s is an inputted string by the user using Scanner which is then turned all uppercase, could that be the problem?

Comment: It worlks fine for me. It prints out:10410110810811100119111114108100

Comment: How did you read the input? What function did you use? Perhaps you just got the "hello" string alone. Try printing or trace the "s" parameter value first at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @OwenBringino is right. However, instead of doing that just pass "HELLO WORLD" to see if your function is right. If it's right, upload the rest of your code so we can figure out the input issue.

Comment: Use `input.nextLine()` instead of `input.next()`

Answer (score 3):

By default, `Scanner` splits the input text on whitespace, so if you enter `hello world` then the call `scanner.next()` will return `hello`. A second call to `scanner.next()` will return `world`.

**Updated**

Actually, your variable name in the updated question is well named: `wordIn`, since that's exactly what you get. A word.

**Solution**

Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` to get the entire line of text entered by the user.

Comment: So to read in the whole string, i would need another call to `scanner.next`? Would this need another line?